# How to execute a mongodb query in linux script

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb

I got stuck on a problem: I want to delete all the Document less than 3 months in MongoDB, but I want to make the folowing program in a linux script, because 'm new to Linuw world, here's the code :

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
db.user_track.remove( { access_time : {"$lt" : new Date(2019, month-3, 1) } })
```

How to make this tiny program in linux script please (this for linux experts)?
is the mongo query for this purpose is correcte(for Mongo expert)?

Thanks

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think you want `$gt`, not `$lt`. That's because you want to delete `access_datetime >= Date(today, -3 months)`. That should capture records in the interval `[today-3 months, today]`, and keep other records like records 6 months old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to delete all docs less than last 3 months